# powershell - remove first 3 lines and last 4 from each file

Tags: powershell

Hallo guys.
I'm trying to remove first 3 lines and last 4 from all the files within the folder.
Moreover some lines contains leading spaces that I want to remove.

This is what I've done:

```
gci c:/my_folder/ | % {
$path = $_.fullname
$file = gc $_
$file[3..($file.length-4)] | % {$_.trimstart()} | out-file $path
}
```

I can't understand why at the end of the script ALL the files contain the same text.
It seems that my variables don't change values within the script.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. What do you see when you output each line getting written to the file?

Comment: Hi. I've seen your comment just now. For example if I write gci c:/my_folder | % {gc $_}  powershell always displays the content of first file for each of them. If I modify $_ in $_.fullname everything works fine. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I supposed I was looping always the same file. I needed to modify

```
$file = gc $_
```

in

```
$file = gc $_.fullname
```

Now everything works fine. 
Thanks the same :)